# XHTML5 and custom namespaces not passing validation

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, semantics, markup

This sample code won't pass w3c validator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:foo="http://foo.com/fooxml">
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <foo:TabControl>

    </foo:TabControl>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? What do I need to do to make namespaces to work and pass validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DTD (`http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd`) is "XHTML 1.0 Strict" not "XHTML 1.0 Strict + Foo".

If you want to validate you will need to find or create a DTD that includes all the elements and attributes you are using, and change the Doctype to point at that.

The W3C's list of [recommended Doctypes](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) includes a number of multiple namespace documents (such as XHTML + MathML + SVG) that you could use as examples for creating your own.

Comment: Can I create an XHTML document that is based on the existing HTML DTD (html, head, body, div, ul, etc) and then just add this namespace and use it `foo:TabControl`? I wouldn't want to recreate the entire HTML along with all its elements. Can you make hybrid doctypes?

Comment: XHTML is expressed in modules to make creating mixed namespace documents easier. See the DTDs I suggested as examples in my answer.

Comment: Ah I see. So I just create my own DTD with the elements of my choice, such as `TabControl`, then I create a joined DTD called XHTML+Foo?

Comment: Will a browser render the normal HTML tags?